# Adding TextView dynamicallly in android

Tags: android

I want to create a text field and enter the following “ANDROID, IPHONE, BLACKBERRY, WINDOWS”. On Click of SUBMIT button display the each strings in different text views. This is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        et = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.etext);
         texts = et.getText().toString();

        tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(texts);
}
```

Comment: the number of tokens in input is it constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` your string around `comma`.

in a `for loop` till the length of splitted array, create new `TextView` and attach it as a child to the parent layout (setting appropriate ids)

something like this

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

String[] items = data.split(",");
for (String item : items)
{

    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
    valueTV.setText(item);
    valueTV.setId("textView"+i);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    layout.addView(valueTV);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
public void onClick(View v) {

View parent;  //parent view where to add
ViewGroup layout=new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setLayoutParams(new   ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TextView tv1=new TextView(context);
tv1.setText("Android");
TextView tv2=new TextView(context);
tv2.setText("Blackberry");
TextView tv3=new TextView(context);
tv3.setText("Windows");
TextView tv4=new TextView(context);
tv4.setText("iphone");

 layout.addView(tv1);
 layout.addView(tv2);
 layout.addView(tv3);
 layout.addView(tv4);

parent.addView(layout);

}
```